# How do I create an infinite addition output loop in JS/node?

Tags: javascript, loops, addition, visual-web-developer

I am new to JS. For fun I want to create an infinite loop that outputs the following way:
1+1=2, 2+2=4, 4+4=8, 8+8=16 and so on...This is what I have so far. I created a For loop to concise my theories/methods for practice, but I still can't get it to work properly.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  num1 = i;
  sum = i * 2;
  answer = sum * 2;
  console.log(sum + " + " + sum + " = " + answer * i);
}
```

Comment: You should go through your code line by line, either with a debugger or by hand for a specific value of i. There are some logical errors with your code that you should be able to discover, and debugging is a valuable skill to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're just multiplying variables by two when really you want to take the result of adding two numbers together and use it in the next iteration.

Declare a `step` variable outside of the loop. On each iteration assign the the sum of two steps to an `answer` variable, log the result, and then assign `answer` to `step`.

```js
let step = 1;

for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  let answer = step + step;
  console.log(`${step} + ${step} = ${answer}`);
  step = answer;
}
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)